# INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES property of dependent target is not populated in CMake

Tags: cmake

I've read in few places, [this is one of them](https://leimao.github.io/blog/CMake-Public-Private-Interface/), that when using the meaning of the PUBLIC, PRIVATE and INTERFACE keywords in the context of commands such as `target_include_directories` is as follows:

> PRIVATE - directories after this keyword will be added to the `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property of the target specified. 
> INTERFACE - directories after this keyword will be added to the `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property of the target specified. 
> PUBLIC - directories after this keyword will be added to both. 
>  
> Directories that will be added to the `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` will be added to the `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` of any target dependent on the current target.

OK I run the following experiment:

```
// libmymath/CMakeLists.txt

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

add_library(MyMath src/mymath.cpp)

target_include_directories(MyMath PUBLIC include)

get_target_property(MYMATH_INC_DIR MyMath INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
get_target_property(MYMATH_INC_DIR_INTERFACE MyMath INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)

message("Libmath INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES: ${MYMATH_INC_DIR}") 
message("Libmath INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES INTERFACE: ${MYMATH_INC_DIR_INTERFACE}")
```

```
 calculator/CMakeLists.txt


cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

add_executable(calculator calculator.cpp)



target_link_libraries(calculator MyMath)

get_target_property(CALCULATOR_INC_DIR calculator INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
get_target_property(CALCULATOR_INC_DIR_INTERFACE calculator INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)

message("Calculator INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES: ${CALCULATOR_INC_DIR}") 
message("Calculator INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES INTERFACE: ${CALCULATOR_INC_DIR_INTERFACE}")
```

```
// top-level CMakeLists.txt



cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

project(Math)

add_subdirectory(libmath)
add_subdirectory(calculator)

get_target_property(CALC_INC_DIR calculator INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
get_target_property(CALC_INC_DIR_INTERFACE calculator INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)

message("From top-level CMakeLists.txt: Calculator INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES: ${CALC_INC_DIR}") 
message("From top-level CMakeLists.txt: Calculator INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES: ${CALC_INC_DIR_INTERFACE}")
```

Running this gives:

```
Libmath INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES: /home/yoav/playground/cmake/math/libmath/include
Libmath INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES INTERFACE: /home/yoav/playground/cmake/math/libmath/include
Calculator INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES: CALCULATOR_INC_DIR-NOTFOUND
Calculator INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES INTERFACE: CALCULATOR_INC_DIR_INTERFACE-NOTFOUND
From top-level CMakeLists.txt: Calculator INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES: CALC_INC_DIR-NOTFOUND
From top-level CMakeLists.txt: Calculator INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES: CALC_INC_DIR_INTERFACE-NOTFOUND
```

So we see that the `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property of `calculator` is not populated, although I can see in the `flags.make` file of this target that the `CXX_INCLUDE` variable is set properly !

What gives?

Comment: `Directories that will be added to the INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES will be added to the INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES of any target dependent on the current target.` is this a quote from somewhere or it this your interpretation?

Comment: This is a quote from the source I attached

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Content of target property `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` is actually transferred into property `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` of every target, which *consumes* (with `target_link_libraries` command) given target.

But CMake **defers** all transfers to a consuming target until the **generation** phase, which occurs after whole `CMakeLists.txt` has been processed. This is why one cannot obtain final value of the property using `get_target_property` command: this command can only obtain **current** value of the property, before the transferring.

However, target properties referred by the [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) are expanded to the **final** value. (But again, this expansion is observable only at the generation phase and after it).

One way to see the expanded value of a generator expression is [file(GENERATE)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#generate): this command will create a file, which contains expanded generator expressions.

Example:

```cmake
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project (hello)
add_library(foo SHARED foo.c)
target_include_directories(foo PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
add_library(bar SHARED bar.c)
target_include_directories(bar PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include1)

target_link_libraries(bar PUBLIC foo)

get_target_property(bar_include_directories bar INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)

message(STATUS "bar include directories: ${bar_include_directories}")

file(GENERATE
  OUTPUT bar_include_directories.txt
  CONTENT "include directories: $<TARGET_PROPERTY:bar,INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>\n"
)
```

When configure this CMake project, only **current** value of the property will be printed:

```
build$ cmake ..
-- bar include directories: /home/tester/tests/cmake/include1
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/tester/tests/cmake/build
```

But the file `bar_include_directories.txt` will contain **final** value of the property:

```
$ cat bar_include_directories.txt
include directories: /home/tester/tests/cmake/include1;/home/tester/tests/cmake
```

Answer (score 0):

> Directories that will be added to the INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES will be added to the INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES of any target dependent on the current target.

I believe this is a simple way to explain it that way, but indeed this is not something that can be observed inside cmake scripts, but it's rather "generated" when cmake generates the build system files.

`target_link_libraries` populates `LINK_LIBRARIES` and `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES` properties of a target. Then like after cmake has run all scripts and is generating build files, it goes through `LINK_LIBRARIES` of a target and takes `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` of dependent targets and generates build system files that include these directories for that target.